# Grub installation failed during Ubuntu installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2

I want to use Ubuntu 12.04 Long Term Support  but during installation it showed me a message

> Grub can't be installed.

how can I install manually.

Comment: Is it a dynamic disk? If you install Ubuntu on dynamic disk, the gurb can't be installed.

Comment: what is a dynamic disk

Answer (score 4):

Try with Boot Repair.

### 1 - Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### 2 - Repair the bootloader

To restore the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open a terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running now.

---

#### Glossary

> **[Bootloader](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/telux/lin-club_files/linux-boot/slide0002.htm)**: a piece of code that runs before any operating system is running. A bootloader is used to boot other operating
>   systems. Each operating system usually has its own bootloader.
>
> **[GRUB (*Grand Unified Bootloader*)](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/GRUB-GRand-Unified-Bootloader)**: a bootloader package developed to support multiple operating systems and allow the user to select among them during boot-up. It is Ubuntu's default bootloader.
>
> **[Command, command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the right version of ubuntu?
A fellow of mine got the 64 bit version instead the 32 bit. We spent three days trying to install it ... on an 32 bit pc!
Thinking we had the 32 bit version, we tried a lot of advises and recommendations until we look at sources.list file, in which is recorded the version we were using.
I suggest you check this small issue before anything else.
Regards.

Comment: I think you mean the amd 64 version and the i386 version. Which basically just means 64 bit and 32 bit. There is no ubuntu intel version and no amd version. However there is a 64 bit version and a 32 bit version. Although 64 bit processors are referred to as AMD64 as amd designed quite a lot of the technology behind them there are also 64 bit intel processors.

Comment: unless you're talking Itanium 64-bit - in which case it only works on Itanium processors. AMD64 should work on any PC/laptop purchased in the last few years (except maybe the new arm-based laptops that have recently popped up)

Comment: I apologize. I mean 64 bit version (AMD64). We tried to install it in a core i5 dell pc and in a centrino duo laptop and it does not work.